# How to wait Promise in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have Angular Service which make some http requests, but I need to get headers for those requests from Promise. Here how it works right now, I convert my promise to **Observable**:

```
export class SomeService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  getInfo(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth.getToken().pipe(mergeMap((token: any) => { 
      let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
         })
        }
        return this.http.get(`${this.serverURL}/info`, httpOptions);
    }))
  }
}



getToken() {
   return from(this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY));
}
```

But obviously I have like 20-50 requests and it's not too good to fetch auth token with every request.
I want to fetch my token **once** and use it for all request. Also I have other header which comes from Promise I need to use in my request. So, how can I get my async headers once (probably in constructor) in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off consider if optimizing this code is actually needed. Optimizing for performance is often only useful in parts of code which are run very frequently. When you say you do some 20 to 50 requests it does not sound like it's used a lot (other parts of your app are probably a lot more cpu intensive).

That being said: if you still want to solve this you could indeed fetch the token in your constructor.

```
export class SomeService {
    // We store the observable here for later use
    private getTokenObservable: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthenticationService) {
        // Retrieve the token now and store the observable
        this.getTokenObservable = getToken();
    }

    getInfo(id: string): Observable<any> {
        // Zip the two observables together
        return zip(
            // Re use the previously stored observable
            this.getTokenObservable,
            // Also request the last login
            this.auth.getLastLogin()
        ).pipe(mergeMap((result) => {
            const token = result[0];
            const lastLogin = result[1];

            let httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                })
            }
            return this.http.get(`${this.serverURL}/info`, httpOptions);
        }))
    }
}

getToken() {
    return from(this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY));
}
```

This works because you can subscribe multiple times to the same observable. So we request and store the `getToken` observable only once and then re use it for each request.

Also note how we use the [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) operator provided by rxjs. This allows us to merge two observables together so we can handle the result of both observables in a single function.

Comment: It does make sense, but my second question is I have second header I need to use, like  this.auth.lastLogin() (also from Promise) it means I need to make one more Observable to get it and use it. So code starts to be not readable enough.

Comment: I'll update my answer with how I think you should implement this.

Comment: Trying to execute your example but getting error Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, string, string]>'.

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct `zip` function from the rxjs library? It should be `import { zip } from 'rxjs';`.

Comment: Sorry, now it works, it was imported from rxjs/operators. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate service for getting the token and call the service only once. For next time when you need token check if already you have token value in variable of service, so can skip http request and simply return token to requester.

Answer (score 0):

```
private _tokenObsevable = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
constructor(...) {
    this.auth.getToken().subscribe(token => this._tokenObservable.next(token))
}

getInfo(...) {
this._tokenObservable.pipe(
    switchMap(token => // rest the same
)
```

optional you can create getter like

```
get tokenObservable() {
    return this._tokenObservable.pipe(filter(val => !!val))
}
```

in this case you get only non null values, but also if token won't appeare you'll get stuck

Comment: This is a good one. But, if I need for example get another info from Promise. Let say this.auth.lastLogin(). I need to create one more BehaviorSubject correct?

Comment: i think so, depends what you need to achieve

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can create a utility function in a file and can import it everywhere you need this token, or can create a service if this token is coming form a server call and then can inject it in all the places you need this token.

This token can also be saved in a const files and imported in the place wherever required.